Snowflake Snowsight Dashboard hyperlink text
I am working on a Snowflake dashboard and need help with two issues:

Clickable Links in Table Tile:
I have a table with two fields: title (e.g., "Google") and url (e.g., "https://google.com"). There are multiple records in this table. I want to create a table tile in the Snowflake dashboard where the output shows the title as a clickable link. Clicking on the title should redirect the user to the website specified in the url field. How can I achieve this?

Extending Field Width:
I have a text field called description in my Snowflake dashboard, but the content is not fully visible due to limited field width. Is it possible to extend the field width in the Snowflake dashboard to display the full text? If so, how can I do this?


Any help or guidance on these issues would be greatly appreciated!
[]

I tried to find something in this regard. It is possible in power Bi and other tools but could not find anything similar in snowsight dashboards
I tried to drag the description field and it did not work and I could not find anything else on the internet


Out of curiosity on #1, why not just include both fields in your table tile?  Is that confusing for your users?
